# Integration testing for a single service mocking/stubbing some of the injected components

Tags: integration-testing, mockito, spring-boot, spring-test

I've read hundred of posts and pages but I'm unable to figure the right way to do integration testing mocking just some components.

This is the scenario: I've an application created using Spring Boot (1.2-snapshot) and among various spring libraries, also spring data JPA.

I've several services, for example Service1 and Service2, and they use other components and repositories managed by Spring Data.

If I want to test all the services for a complete integration testing using an embedded hsql database I declare a class this way in my test package:

```
@Transactional
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = AppConfig.class)
public class IntegrationTest {

  @Autowired
  private Service1 s1;

  @Autowired
  private Service2 s2;

  [... test methods ...]

}
```

Where the AppConfig class is instead in my main package, and is defined this way:

```
@ComponentScan
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class AppConfig {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(AppConfig.class, args);
  }

}
```

During the integration testing a complete spring context get defined, all the spring data repositories are built and instantiated as usuale and everything works fine as expected.

But there 2 are scenarios where I need different goals:

1) I want to test just one service at a time (e.g.: Service1), for example  because Service2 is very slow to initialize, and I want to test it in a different test class.
How do I achieve this goal? The problem is that I still need all the Dependency Injection, and in particular all the spring data manages repositories that Service1 autowires on itself. If I was not using spring-data repositories I could new() the Service1 class by myself and then wire all the dependencies by hand, even this would be very cumbersome.

2) While testing Service1, I would like do mock/stub just one of all his dependencies. For example I would simulate a component that in production connects to external services.
I don't know how to selectively inject a stubbed object on the spring context while continuing to use all the others as usual.

Some help on the subject would be very welcome.

Comment: Any updates on the approach you followed or suggested? I am also in need of a similar requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using Mockito mocks you can create different test beans that are set up on different profiles and then execute the tests with those profiles.

FOr example (of course it's just a vision of how you can do it not the exact solution) you could add a profile 'fast' and run your tests with @ActiveProfiles('fast'). Then you would have test configurations annotated with @Profile('fast') that would set up all the beans that you need